# Android WebView pinchToZoom doesn't work correctly inside ScrollView

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have WebView inside a ScrollView and the WebView zoom functionality doesn't work correctly, because the ScrolView take focus and scrolls instead to zoom WebView.

I was thinking, that putting WebView inside ScrollView isn't the best idea, but unfortunately I don't know how else I can achieve wanted result.

I need to have few TextViews on the top of the screen and under them WebView which will show HTML content, but when I didn't use ScollView I can't see the whole content (scroll down of course).

So anybody has an idea how I can achieve scrolling without ScrollView or zooming WebView in ScrollView correctly?

Thank you!

[image: WebView inside ScrollView]

Comment: did you find a solution for that?